# Get data from Clipboard to DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, clipboard, data-conversion

I am trying to convert the content of a Clipboard to Datatable.

I was trying to use the following code from the URL: http://www.seesharpdot.net/?p=221

```
private void PasteFromExcel()

    {
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        tbl.TableName = "ImportedTable";
        List<string> data = new List<string>(ClipboardData.Split('\n'));
        bool firstRow = true;

        if (data.Count > 0 && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data[data.Count - 1]))
        {
            data.RemoveAt(data.Count - 1);
        }

        foreach (string iterationRow in data)
        {
            string row = iterationRow;
            if (row.EndsWith("\r"))
            {
                row = row.Substring(0, row.Length - "\r".Length);
            }

            string[] rowData = row.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\x09' });
            DataRow newRow = tbl.NewRow();
            if (firstRow)
            {
                int colNumber = 0;
                foreach (string value in rowData)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
                    {
                        tbl.Columns.Add(string.Format("[BLANK{0}]", colNumber));
                    }
                    else if (!tbl.Columns.Contains(value))
                    {
                        tbl.Columns.Add(value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tbl.Columns.Add(string.Format("Column {0}", colNumber));
                    }
                    colNumber++;
                }
                firstRow = false;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < rowData.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (i >= tbl.Columns.Count) break;
                    newRow[i] = rowData[i];
                }
                tbl.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
        }

        this.WorkingTableElement.WorkingTable = tbl;

        tableImportGrid.DataSource = null;
        tableImportGrid.RefreshDataSource();

        tableImportGrid.DataSource = tbl;
        tableImportGrid.RefreshDataSource();
        tableImportGrid.Refresh();
    }
```

But the following part of the code:

```
        List<string> data = new List<string>(ClipboardData.Split('\n'));
```

is causing me some trouble. I understand that the ClipboardData should already refer to Clipboard content, but I tried to do that with DataObject, but this did not work.

Maybe someone has a good idea how to implement this or some guidelines how to go forward. I have not been exposed to C# much and mostly done my programming in Python.

Comment: What error do you get? Can you provide more information on what trouble its causing you?

Comment: The issue was that the DataType was incorrect as @pixelbadger mentioned in his response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split is a function available to the String class, so I'd assume ClipboardData should be a string.

This can be retrieved by calling: `System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText()`, rather than `Clipboard.GetDataObject()`, which I assume you are calling at the moment.

On calling the `GetText()` method, the selected cells are converted to their textual representation, with each cell separated by a space (or tab?), and each line separated by a newline character (`'\n'`). Something like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
a b c d e f
```

TL;DR; you should call `Clipboard.GetText()`, rather than `Clipboard.GetDataObject()`.

Comment: Hi! This indeed solved my problem, But I am unsure how to make sure that the Column names do not get assigned from the Clipboard.